# Prevent code execution in Eclipse Graphic Layout preview

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, draw, graphic

I want to draw a custom view, which have the draw method:

```
@Override 
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    if(!path.isEmpty())
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

In Eclipse Graphic Layout preview I get a NullPointerException. (because of course for Graphic Layout preview path is null). Is there any way (for example using @ or other instructions) to prevent Graphic Layout preview from execution of

```
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override 
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    if(path != null && !path.isEmpty())
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Comment: I have found the solution - also paint is null for Graphic Layout, because it only go to onDraw() method and doesn't see anything else. Thank you for help.